# Turn off Virtual Keyboard for one control in FireMonkey Android app

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

What's the best way to turn off the virtual keyboard for a particular `FMX.Edit.TEdit` control?

Is it to use `VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Never;` in the `OnEnter` event and `VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.DefinedBySystem;` in the `OnExit` event? I'm not entirely happy with this approach, as if something doesn't go according to plan, the virtual keyboard is hidden for every control in the app.

Or just use `Keyboard.HideVirtualKeyboard;` in the `OnEnter` event? This sort of works, but if you click into the control a second time, the keyboard appears.

I can see the control has a `KeyboardType` property, but **None** is not one of the available choices.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:

I cannot set `ReadOnly` to true, as it is being used for capturing the text from a barcode scanner.

EDIT:

Since `VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.Never;` works the majority of the time I'll just continue to use that method, but add extra event handlers to use `VKAutoShowMode := TVKAutoShowMode.DefinedBySystem;` when other edit controls get the focus.

Comment: The ReadOnly property is supposed to prevent the virtual keyboard from showing

Comment: How about not using a `TEdit` but e.g. a `TLabel` or `TText` control instead?

Comment: You cannot type into a TLabel, so that does not work with the scanner, which is a HID, and the TText is just for managing text styling and does not receive text input itself.